# Swift: Detect when another app's notification shows up

Tags: swift, notifications

I would like to know if there is any way to detect whenever a notification show up from the status bar. I couldn't find any help about this on Stack Overflow or any other website.

I'm developing a game and I want to pause the game when notifications show up so a player won't be disadvantaged. (Notifications hide a some players' buttons.)